# Alternatives to VB6 COM+ Components with PHP?

Tags: php, vb6, components, com+

I have a Classic ASP web application that calls VB6 COM+ components primarily to interact with a SQL Server database (MS N-tier design at the time). These components (in a COM+ application) either fetch data from the database and return HTML snippets, or receive data (as part of a transaction started in ASP methods) and return (or not) HTML snippets. And of course, I frequently used the context of the web app within the code.

I'm not touching this working web app (has run flawlessly for ten years) but for a new project, I guess I don't have the option to use these VB6 compiled transactional components for other platforms, primarily PHP web apps. And I really want to stay clear of .NET anything unless I can write such components and they can be used by PHP.

So, what is the state of the art (open source) for handing off the duties of transactional VB6 COM+ components that have access to the web app context in PHP? Compiled PHP (does it exist?), java (servlets???), ??? I really don't know what will optimally interact with a database, "vote" in transactions, and has access to the web app context, and can work with several platforms.

Any discussion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well you could use .Net and create a custom web service, then all platforms could consume that service with externals requests using http, sockets, or what have you.

Comment: It seems MS is pushing WCF with lack of support for .NET services sometime in the future???

Answer (score 0):

You can [call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) VB6 components from PHP.

Comment: But do I really want to develop new components with VB6? I don't think so. It seems that MS now pushes folks toward WCF (on Windows server platforms). Is there anything comparable to COM+ components (i.e. transactional, access to session variables, etc.) in the Apache/PHP world?